# Google PubSub returning google.gax.errors.GaxError: GaxError RPC failed caused by ... StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

We're trying to do a simple publish to an existing topic after an event on one of our distributed systems.

The code looks like:

```
try:
  dat = data.encode('utf-8')
  topic.publish(dat)
except:
  <code to recover>
```

If we catch all with the except and print the trace back, we get:

> google.gax.errors.GaxError: GaxError(RPC failed, caused by
>   <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE,
>   {"created":"@1478711654.067744009","description":"Secure read
>   failed","file":"src/core/lib/security/transport/secure_endpoint.c","file_line":157,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1478711654.067706801","description":"EOF","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.c","file_line":235}]})>

(full error below)

Looking at http://gcloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pubsub-topic.html#google.cloud.pubsub.topic.Topic.publish, it doesn't seem like this GAX error is something we should be looking to catch.  However, if we *do* catch the error and use exponential backoff to retry, this normally works the second time.

I found [this discussion](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1869) and while it speaks to a potential error in `_gax_python` it doesn't seem to be relevant.  Any thoughts on what we might be doing wrong here?

Full error:

```
458    Traceback (most recent call last):
   459      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
   460        self.run()
   461      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
   462        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
   463      File "/home/pp/pp/pp/process/uploader.py", line 145, in upload_thread
   464        topic.publish(byte_string)
   465      File "/home/pp/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub/topic.py", line 257, in publish
   466        message_ids = api.topic_publish(self.full_name, [message_data])
   467      File "/home/pp/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub/_gax.py", line 165, in topic_publish
   468        options=options)
   469      File "/home/pp/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/gapic/pubsub/v1/publisher_api.py", line 289, in publish
   470        return self._publish(request, options)
   471      File "/home/pp/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 481, in inner
   472        return api_caller(api_call, this_settings, request)
   473      File "/home/pp/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 158, in inner
   474        return a_func(request, **kwargs)
   475      File "/home/pp/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 434, in inner
   476        errors.create_error('RPC failed', cause=exception))
   477      File "/home/pp/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/future/utils/__init__.py", line 419, in raise_with_traceback
   478        raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
   479      File "/home/pp/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 430, in inner
   480        return a_func(*args, **kwargs)
   481      File "/home/pp/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 64, in inner
   482        return a_func(*updated_args, **kwargs)
   483      File "/home/pp/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 481, in __call__
   484        return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, False, deadline)
   485      File "/home/pp/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 432, in _end_unary_response_blocking
   486        raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
   487    google.gax.errors.GaxError: GaxError(RPC failed, caused by <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, {"created":"@1478711654.067744009","description":"Secure read failed","file":"src/core/lib/security/transport/secure_endpoint.c","file_line":157,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1478711654.067706801","description":"EOF","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.c","file_line":235}]})>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the relevant discussion you're looking for is issue 2683, "[Frequent gRPC StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE errors](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2683)".

You're not doing anything wrong, and it seems like catching the exception and retrying is the most appropriate workaround at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If the topic is a global variable it stops producing the error. Make the topic a class variable and only instantiate it once - only call this line once:

```
topic = pubsub.Client().topic(name)
```

Also, seems like this only works for Python 2.7 - in Python 3.6 retrying numbs the pain a little.

Disabling gRPC does the trick for Python 3.6 - this can be done by setting the environment variable:

```
ENV GOOGLE_CLOUD_DISABLE_GRPC=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get a "not so pretty" workaround. Using a policy that replicates code for deadline_exceeded on [google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber.policy.thread.Policy.on_exception](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/pubsub/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/policy/thread.py#L128).

```
from google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber.policy.thread import Policy
import grpc

class UnavailableHackPolicy(Policy):
    def on_exception(self, exception):
        """
        There is issue on grpc channel that launch an UNAVAILABLE exception now and then. Until
        that issue is fixed we need to protect our consumer thread from broke.
        https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2683
        """
        unavailable = grpc.StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        if getattr(exception, 'code', lambda: None)() in [unavailable]:
            print("¡OrbitalHack! - {}".format(exception))
            return
        return super(UnavailableHackPolicy, self).on_exception(exception)
```

On receive message function i have a code like

```
subscriber = pubsub.SubscriberClient(policy_class=UnavailableHackPolicy)
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project, subscription_name)
subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback, flow_control=flow_control)
```

Problem is that when the resource it is truly UNAVAILABLE we will be not aware. However while GRPC developer team manage to fix this issue we will be using this workaround.